# JS: toISOString() no da la diferencia de horas correctas dentro de un rango de fechas

Tags: javascript, date

Dentro del rango de fechas 07/03 - 01/11 la hora dada por toISOString() es 21:00:00, mientras fuera de ese rango el resultado es 20:00:00, el cual es correcto porque la región donde yo vivo se utiliza la zona horaria central (EE.UU. y Canadá) y hay 5 horas de diferencia contra la hora UTC.

En el ejemplo son las 15:00:00, lo cual en la hora UTC deberían ser las 20:00:00 horas, pero como ya mencioné dentro de ese rango de fechas me da las 21:00:00.

```js
let t1 = (new Date('2020-03-07T15:00:00')).toISOString();
let t2 = (new Date('2020-11-01T15:00:00')).toISOString();
let t3 = (new Date('2020-03-08T15:00:00')).toISOString();
let t4 = (new Date('2020-10-31T15:00:00')).toISOString();

// 6 horas de diferencia:
console.log(`Hora Incorrecta...: ${t1}`);
console.log(`Hora Incorrecta...: ${t2}`);
// 5 horas de diferencia:
console.log(`Hora Correcta.....: ${t3}`);
console.log(`Hora Correcta.....: ${t4}`);
```

Comment: No entiendo a qué te refieres ni cuál es tu pregunta

Comment: Hola ArtMagic, creas tres objetos fecha, los tres tienen la misma hora, imprimes las tres fechas, todas muestran la misma hora, y tu dices que la segunda es incorrecta, estás creando bien la fecha, la estás mostrando bien... acá no hay ningún problema, o si?.

Answer (score 2):

Mira la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString#ejemplos) y veras lo que espera de entrada la función toISOString(), si la usas bien, funciona bien. Un saludo.

```js
//    let t1 = (new Date('2020-04-04T18:00:00')).toISOString();  
//    let t2 = (new Date('2020-02-04T18:00:00')).toISOString();
//    let t3 = (new Date('2020-08-04T18:00:00')).toISOString();

let t1 = new Date('04 April 2020 18:00 UTC').toISOString();
let t2 = new Date('04 February 2020 18:00 UTC').toISOString();
let t3 = new Date('04 August 2020 18:00 UTC').toISOString();

console.log(`Hora Correcta.....: ${t1}`);
console.log(`Hora NO Incorrecta: ${t2}`);
console.log(`Hora Correcta.....: ${t3}`);
```